# How to Edit App .desktop File Installed by Snap?

Tags: lubuntu, snap, .desktop, lxqt

As you can see in the photo, I need to edit `Telegram` desktop file, the thing is that I installed the app using `Snap`.

Lubuntu: 22.04.

LXQT Desktop enviroment.

---

**Why do I need to edit `Telegram` desktop file?**

so that I can configure scaling for the app, [learn more](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/pixelated-images-in-telegram-under-fractional-scaling-in-kde/28454/4).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That the application is installed as a snap should not prevent you from editing it's `.desktop`-file. I also don't see the need to edit this `.desktop`-file , at least not in your screenshot.

However, you can copy the corresponding `.desktop`-file from `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the copy instead with the text editor of your choice without the need of root privileges.

`.desktop`-files with the same name in `~/.local/share/applications/` take precedence over `.desktop`-files in the system-wide locations like `/usr/share/applications/` (for deb-packages) and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` (for snaps) and will not be overwritten with a new original by an upgrade.

Comment: Ma man, it worked. I need to edit Telegram desktop file so that I can solve scaling issues in the app, [learn more.](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/pixelated-images-in-telegram-under-fractional-scaling-in-kde/28454/4)